# How to start selenium chromedriver script with already opened profile in chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium chromedriver with Google Chrome profiles on Mac OS and Windows. As I understand it, in the usual case the selenium script will not work if another profile in Google Chrome is open. This causes some inconvenience as a regular google chrome user - every time before I run the script I have to close the browser completely.

I would not be comfortable switching to the gecko driver because firefox does not allow me to install the extensions I need. Are there any other options on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Creating a new Chrome Profile?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I do not need to create new Chrome profile. I need to use google chrome at the same time selenium script is working